# Django: Foreignkey query

Tags: python, django

I have models.py as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    subject = models.CharField("과목명", max_length=10)
    ...

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    professor = models.CharField("출제교수", max_length=4)
    ...
```

Views.py:

```
def get_q_table(request):
    context = {
        "q_list" : Question.objects.all().order_by("number")
    }
    return render(request, "q_table.html", context)
```

I want to somehow pass related  instance to q_table.html, but can't find a way to do that. I should be something like below (Of course, it not quite right. I've been looking up documentations of foreign key queries but i cannot figure a way out':

```
def get_q_table(request):
context = {
    "q_list" : Question.objects.all().order_by("number")
    "article" : Question.objects.all().related_board
}
return render(request, "q_table.html", context)
```

If I figure a way out, then the following template should work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h3>{{article.subject}} : {{article.year}}년 {{article.semester}}학기 {{article.quarter}}Q</h3></div>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group" id="visitorbook">
        {% for question in questions %}
            <li class="list-group-item">{{question.number}} : {{ question.question }} - {{ question.answer }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select your article explicitly and then select all related questions, I guess.

Try this:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id)
questions = article.question_set.all()
context = {
    "article" : article
    "questions" : questions
}
```

General info on using related objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

When it comes to order: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering

Answer (score 1):

In template, think it should be:

```
{% for question in q_list %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fetch aricle objects;

`articles = Article.objects.all()`

```
{% for article in  articles %}
<div class="container">
     <div class="page-header"><h3>{{article.subject}} : {{article.year}}년 {{article.semester}}학기 {{article.quarter}}Q</h3></div>
     <div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="visitorbook">
     {% for question in article.question_set.all %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{question.number}} : {{question.question }} - {{ question.answer }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

if you want fetch only one article, then;

```
articles = Article.objects.get(id=id)`


<div class="container">
     <div class="page-header"><h3>{{article.subject}} : {{article.year}}년 {{article.semester}}학기 {{article.quarter}}Q</h3></div>
     <div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="visitorbook">
     {% for question in article.question_set.all %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{question.number}} : {{question.question }} - {{ question.answer }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided, that the article is the same for all questions, you can try something like this:

```
{% with article=questions.0.article %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h3>{{article.subject}} : {{article.year}}년 {{article.semester}}학기 {{article.quarter}}Q</h3></div>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</div>

{% endwith %}
```

Though you should also handle the case when the questions list is empty in the way that is the most suitable for you situation. Also note, that you wouldn't need to add "article" to the context.